# Replacing a value in all rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have about 50 or so records in a table, I need a sql statement that will update all the referral column ids that are 5 to 9. How would I apply this to every record that applies?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET referral_column_id = 9
WHERE referral_column_id = 5;
```

Comment: @Tomalak- Not a fan of the backticks myself.

Comment: I get seasick when I see backticks.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE `table_name` SET `column_id` = 9 WHERE `column_id` = 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE col SET referral = 9 WHERE referral =5
```